# CodeIgniter get user by username

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to get user info by username. but return null..

here my code getting by ID -(This is working)

```
public function get($id = null){
        if($this->access_app()){
            if($id == null){
                $this->output->set_status_header(404, "Id Vazio");
                echo json_encode(array("code" => 404, "message" => "Id Vazio"));
            }else{
                $this->load->database();
                $this->db->where("id", $id);
                $query = $this->db->get("cliente");
                if($query->num_rows()==0){
                    $this->output->set_status_header(404, "Id nao existe");
                echo json_encode(array("code" => 404, "message" => "Id Nao existe"));
                }else{
                    echo json_encode($query->row());
                }
            }
            
        }
```

and this get by username - (Is not working)
return null..

```
public function getByUsername($username=null){
        if($this->access_app()){
            if($username == null){
                $this->output->set_status_header(404, "username Vazio");
                echo json_encode(array("code" => 404, "message" => "username Vazio"));
            }else{
                $this->load->database();
                $this->db->where("username", $username);
                $query = $this->db->get("cliente");
                if($query->num_rows()==0){
                    $this->output->set_status_header(404, "username nao existe");
                echo json_encode(array("code" => 404, "message" => "username Nao existe"));
                }else{
                    echo json_encode($query->row());
                }
            }
            
        }
```

could you help me? Please!

Comment: where does `$username` come from? from a model? can you show that code, did you debug it, to check if it has a value?

Comment: @Vickel.. Yes it come from my model.. I am using postman to test.. and this is an API

Comment: ok great, but how can we know, WHY $username is null? you need to show the code generating the variable

Comment: Hello @Vickel, sorry to take late to aswer you.. bud i did it and it's working...............                          `public function getData() {
        if($this->access_app()){
          
            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $this->load->database();
            $this->db->where('username', $username);
            $this->db->where('status', 1);
            $data = $this->db->get('cliente')->row();

            echo json_encode($data);
            
        }
      }`

Comment: You are welcome to [answer your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)